# Test arrays of paired words to find out which letters the pairs share

Tags: r, apply

What I want to do is use apply instead of a loop to compare two arrays of character string by each row e.g. row one of x.str with row one of y.str.

x.str

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "c"  "o"  "m"  "e" 
[2,] "g"  "o"  "n"  "e" 
[3,] "b"  "o"  "o"  "d" 
[4,] "f"  "i"  "n"  "e"
```

y.str

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "t"  "o"  "o"  "t" 
[2,] "j"  "a"  "m"  "m" 
[3,] "b"  "e"  "e"  "n" 
[4,] "l"  "e"  "t"  "s"
```

If I was going to write it as a loop:

```
A = array(0,dim=dim(x.str1))
for(i in 1:length(x.str[,1])){
    A[i,] = ifelse(x.str[i,] %in% y.str[i,],1,0)
}
```

With the out put:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    1    1    0
[2,]    0    0    1    0
[3,]    1    0    0    0
[4,]    0    1    0    0
```

However, the dimension of the real arrays will be approx.

```
array(0,dim=c(10000,12)
```

Thus I wanted to use apply instead as much quicker than a loop. I've look all over this site and other and tried many different ways but cant work out how to select the current row being processed within apply to use in the function. Similar post have suggested using:

```
nrow()
rownames()
```

I've used them like:

```
stringCom = function(x){
     i = nrow(x)
     ifelse(x.str[i,] %in% y.str1[i,],0,1)
}
apply(x.str,1,stringCom)
```

but all I keep getting is errors. I have tried:

```
test = function(x){

  r = nrow(x)
  r
}
apply(x.str,1,test)
```

Which just gives NULL as its output. Similar thing happens with rownames, NROW, names etc. I'm sure there is probably a very simple answer but can not seem to find it.

Any suggestions/help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your desired output makes no sense to me. I'm totally lost as to what is being checked.

Comment: I wanted to compare lists of paired words to find out which letters the pairs share with each other, working out the total number they share, the total number of unique letters they share and the position of the shared letters. The only way I could figure out to do this was with %in% and doing this twice a%in%b and b%in%a without writing multiple loops to test letter by letter. I have realized that the output was wrong above as that was the output for y.str %in% x.str (sorry about that). Hope this helps and thanks for taking the time to reply.

Comment: Ok, each row of x.str/y.str represents the constituent letters of a word. You want to test if each individual **letter** in a row of y.str is in the **corresponding row of x.str**.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I wanted to do

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate two things at once, it's better to use some form of `mapply`. Here's some sample input data

```
x.str<-matrix(strsplit("cgbfoooimnoneede","")[[1]], ncol=4)
y.str<-matrix(strsplit("tjbloaeeomettmns","")[[1]], ncol=4)
```

then you could do something like

```
t(mapply(function(a,b) a%in%b, 
    split(x.str, row(x.str)), split(y.str, row(y.str)))+0)

#   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# 1    0    1    0    0
# 2    0    0    0    0
# 3    1    0    0    0
# 4    0    0    0    1
```

which returns the same thing as the code you wrote

```
A = array(0,dim=dim(x.str))
for(i in 1:length(x.str[,1])){
    A[i,] = ifelse(x.str[i,] %in% y.str[i,],1,0)
}
A
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    0    1    0    0
# [2,]    0    0    0    0
# [3,]    1    0    0    0
# [4,]    0    0    0    1
```

But it's not always true that for loops are slow. You should be sure to benchmark different strategies to see what works best for any given application. The biggest bottleneck is usual memory management. As long as your predefine the needed memory for the result, the for loop can often be faster.

Comment: Thank you for this fairly new to programming and not fluent in programming speak yet so find it hard to understand the technical differences between similar function like apply mapply etc. So quick question is "predefining the memory needed" making sure I predefining, where possible, array sizes at the beginning of a script (e.g. A = array(0,dim=dim(x.str))) before implementing loop, functions etc that use them?